# How to move html element down as browser window resizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm working on a project using react in the front-end and node.js and express in the back-end. Now I'm using CSS grid and flexbox to make it responsive.

So when I resize my browser all but one elements resize the way I want them to. The only one that doesn't is an <hr /> element. It's a horizontal line that separates the header from some content. I would like for it to move downwards a bit when the browser gets resized since at the moment it the header moves into it, here's a screenshot of the window when it gets resized: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLsAD.jpg

Here's the html that my main react component returns:

```
<div id="Home">
  <div id="Navbar">
    <h1 id="title">Kepos</h1>
    <div>
      <h2 id="home" className="pages">Home</h2>
      <a href="browse"><h2 id="browse" className="pages"> Browse</h2></a>
      <a href="search"><h2 id="search" className="pages">Search</h2></a>
      <a href="join-us"><h2 id="joinUs" className="pages">Join us</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="HomeHeader">
    <img src={logo} alt="Kepos Logo" id="logo" />
    <h1 id="headerText">Lorem Ipsum <br /> dolor sit amet</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutSeparator">
    <h3 id="breakOneTitle">About us</h3>
    <hr id="breakOne" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
#Home {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #161619;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4vw 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 7vh 78vh 5vh 1fr;
}

#Navbar {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/5; 
}

#HomeHeader {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#aboutSeparator {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 128px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 3vh 2vh;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#breakOneTitle {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #DD8377;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

hr {
    color: #DD8377;
    background-color: #DD8377;
}

#breakOne {
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px; 
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  width: 54vw;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
```

Also here's the CSS for the homeheader component (for the children of the HomeHeader div in the html)

```
#HomeHeader {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 28vw 10vw 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 4vh 68vh 3vh;
}

#logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  max-width: 40vw;
}

#headerText {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  max-width: 60vw;
}
```

So that's my question. How would I go about moving the line downwards as the window gets smaller.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your HTML and CSS

Comment: You're right, @Dai I'm sorry, I edited my post to include it!

Comment: `NavBar` and `Homeheader` I guess are react components rather than HTML elements, could we see the resulting HTML instead? I think React is largely irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Sure! I added the CSS and html except for the CSS of the NavBar component I don't think it's very relevant but if you want me to add it tell me!

Comment: Why dont you use media queries for the specified resize of the screen and modify the CSS the way you want it to look?

Comment: I've thought about that but I'd like to know if there's another way before that,,,

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding a div instead of `<hr/>` and giving it a percantage or view height
also you can add media queries

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).